# Call a generic non-static method with dynamic type and generic callback as parameter

Tags: c#, generics, mono

Developing an app for Android (and later iOS) using Xamarin/Mono. Normally I use this code to call a non-static generic method and it works great:

```
serverService.GetCustomListObject<T> (firstRequestInLine,
                                      null,
                                      onGetCustomListObjectFromThread<T>,
                                      onGetCustomListObjectFromThreadError);
```

where the callbacks are defined as:

```
private void onGetCustomListObjectFromThread<T> (List<T> list, 
                                                 RequestStateGen<T>.SuccessfullDelegateType successDel
{ ... }
```

and

```
private void onGetCustomListObjectFromThreadError (String error,
                                                   WebRequest failedRequest)
{ ... }
```

However, now I need to call `GetCustomListObject<t>` where `t` is set dynamically. I am quite new to generics but have tried the following code from other examples without success:

```
typeof(ServerService).GetMethod ("GetCustomListObject").MakeGenericMethod (t).Invoke (serverService, new object[] {
        firstRequestInLine,
        null,
        typeof(LocalServerService).GetMethod ("onGetCustomListObjectFromThread").MakeGenericMethod (t),
        typeof(LocalServerService).GetMethod ("onGetCustomListObjectFromThreadError")
        });
```

where `LocalServerService` is the class all my examples here are in and `serverService` is of type `ServerService`

I get the following error:

```
Error: Ambiguous matching in method resolution
```

**Edit:** GetCustomListObject in ServerService:

```
public void GetCustomListObject<T> (WebRequest request,
                                    RequestStateGen<T>.SuccessfullDelegateType successDelegate,
                                    RequestStateGen<T>.InternalSuccessDelegateType internalSuccessDelegate,
                                    RequestStateGen<T>.ErrorDelegateType errorDelegate)
```

Comment: Are there any other method overloads for `GetCustomListObject` or `onGetCustomListObjectFromThread` or `onGetCustomListObjectFromThreadError` ? i.e. same name but different signature? I wonder if the `GetMethod` is what is throwing...

Comment: Where *exactly* does the error occur? It would probably be useful if you'd break all this up so that you've got separate statements for each reflection call.

Comment: No, there a no duplicate method names. I'm very unsure that the 3rd and 4th argument are structured correctly as I don't have a reference to the instance of my `LocalServerService`

Comment: I separated the code a bit, it's crashing on the third argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original code, you were calling a method passing in delegates.

In your reflection code, you appear to be passing in `MethodInfo` values instead - I don't believe they will automatically be converted to delegates.

Unfortunately it's hard to give a good code sample without knowing the declaration of your `GetCustomListObject` method, but you want *something* like:

```
Type thirdArgType = typeof(Foo<>).MakeGenericGenericType(t);
MethodInfo thirdArgMethod = typeof(LocalServerService)
                                .GetMethod("onGetCustomListObjectFromThread",
                                           BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                                .MakeGenericMethod(t);
Delegate thirdArg = Delegate.CreateDelegate(thirdArgType, this, thirdArgMethod);

MethodInfo fourthArgMethod = typeof(LocalServerService)
                                 .GetMethod("onGetCustomListObjectFromThreadError",
                                            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
Delegate fourthArg = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Bar), this, fourthArgMethod);

MethodInfo method = typeof(ServerService).GetMethod("GetCustomListObject")
                                         .MakeGenericMethod (t);
method.Invoke(serverService,
    new object[] {firstRequestInline, null, thirdArg, fourthArg });
```

Comment: Thanks! Almost there now. I assume it is supposed to be `method.Invoke (serverService, new object[] { firstRequestInLine, null, thirdArg, fourthArg });` on the last row?

Comment: *I added `fouthArg` cause that callback needed to be generic as well